# Drop down no muestra datos

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, pdo, grocery-crud

Tengo la solucion.

Unicamente debia de cambiar unas fucniones

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['action'])) {
switch ($_REQUEST['action']) {
    case 'actualizar':



        // Recupero el id del campo hidden

        $alm->__SET('acro_documento', $_REQUEST['acro_documento']);
        $alm->__SET('acro_subcategoria', $_REQUEST['acro_sub']);
        $alm->__SET('tipo_documento', $_REQUEST['tipo_documento']);
        $alm->__SET('registro_calidad', $_REQUEST['registro_calidad']);
        $alm->__SET('calidad_code', $_REQUEST['calidad_code']);
        $alm->__SET('cod_tempo', $_REQUEST['cod_tempo']);

        $update_results = $model->Actualizar($alm, $_POST['id']);


        header('Location: index2.php');

        break;
```

Donde tengo acronimo_subcategoria le decia que me recuperara por $_REQUEST el mismo campo, y el select se llamaba de otra manera, unicamente con cambiarle aqui el valor lo coge perfectamente.

Unicamente me queda conseguir que al pulsar el boton editar el select recoga el valor de dicho campo, eso ya es mas visual que otra cosa, pero quedaria mejor.
Espero que alguno le pueda ayudar.

--------Post Inicial----

Vale. Tengo dos tablas Tabla subcategorias que contiene: subcategoria y descripcion. Tabla tipodocumentos que contiene: tipo, subcategoria y descripcion. Necesito que en la tabla tipodocumentos se muestre un drop down list que contengan todas las subcategorias existentes de la primera tabla. Esto lo consigo pero no soy capaz de añadirlo en la segunda tabla porque se cree que la modificacion o inserccion la quiero hacer en la primera y tira error de clave primaria repetida por ejemplo

```
<select id="teamlist" name="teamlist">
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=deimos1', 'root', '');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('Select acro_sub from subcategoria');
$stmt->execute();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
echo '<option>' . $row['acro_sub'] . '</option>'; }?>
</select>
```

Pero ahora debo de combinarlo con este otro que recoge los datos para editar

```
<td><input type="" name="acro_subcategoria"  value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('acro_subcategoria') : ''; ?>" style="width:100%;" required /></td>
```

Porque queda de la siguiente manera

https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8WEX.jpg

Y al pulsar editar quiero que recoga el dato que obtiene y si modifico en el select se modifique en el de al lado, se que es un poco complicado pero gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: Sí que es complicado, pues te he leído y no acabo de entender lo que quieres hacer. Despégate 10 minutos de la pantalla, piensa el problema, ponle palabras y explicanoslo como si no supiésemos **nada** de informática. El problema a veces es que ni siquiera el que lo tiene sabe explicarlo... entonces la cosa se hace difícil. Y a veces no lo entiendes porque te lo estás planteando mal, porque no sabes ponerle palabras, no sabes describir lo que ocurre, lo que quieres lograr, etc. Se necesita **primero comprender**, luego que se comprende entonces **se escribe código**. A todos nos pasa. Ánimo.

Comment: Vale.
Tengo dos tablas 
Tabla categorias que contiene: Acronimo y descripcion.
Tabla subcategorias que contiene: Acronimo, subcategoria y descripcion.

Necesito que en la tabla subcategorias se muestre un drop down list que contengan todas las categorias existentes de la primera tabla.
Esto lo consigo pero no soy capaz de añadirlo en la segunda tabla porque se cree que la modificacion o inserccion la quiero hacer en la primera y tira error de clave primaria repetida por ejemplo

Comment: Creo que es mejor que edites la pregunta y que en ella expliques y expongas el problema con la mayor claridad posible. De eso modo seguro que obtendrás ayuda de forma más eficaz.

Comment: esta pregunta ya esta resuelta?

Comment: Si arriba antes de la pregunta deje la solución por si en un futuro puede ayudar a alguien.